# Inheritance troubles between java and scala. Overriding an abstract method reports that I'm "overriding nothing"

Tags: scala

I'm extremely frustrated with this one.

**Java side:**

I have a Java class with some GUI code generated by Netbeans. I've modified the class so that it is abstract, and has abstract methods for each of the GUI buttons.

I've omitted a bunch of the boilerplate code, but the core of the class is this:

```
public abstract class GuiApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  /**
   * Creates new form GuiApp
   */
  public GuiApp() {
    initComponents();
  }


  /**
   * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
   * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
   * regenerated by the Form Editor.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
  private void initComponents() {
      // bunch of initialization of the GUI componenets 
  } 

  abstract void startBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt);
```

So, almost completely NetBeans' code. The only modification that has been done is making the class and it's single method abstract.

**Scala:**

I extend this `GuiApp.java` in a Scala class.

```
class AnotherTestClass extends GuiApp {

}
```

First thing to notice: No warnings from my IDE. It doesn't recognize `GuiApp` as having methods which need to be implemented. So I do it myself:

```
class AnotherTestClass extends GuiApp {
  override def startBtnMouseClicked(evt: MouseEvent): Unit = {
    println("Hello world?")
  }
}
```

At this point, the IDE now complains, but only to say that:

> Method startBtnMouseClicked overrides nothing

What is going on here?

#### EDIT:

I'm... an idiot. So the reason it wasn't working was because I had these two classes in different packages. I got used to Scala's default access modifier of `public` and *completely* forgot that Java's default modifier is `package-private`. Thus, being that the method inside of `GuiApp` looked like this:

abstract void startBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt);

the method I was trying to override was completely invisible to `AnotherTestClass`. Adding a correct modifier to the `GuiApp` class fixed the problem.

```
protected abstract void startBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt);
```

Not a smart man..

Comment: Answer your own question on this and tag it as the answer.  This isn't a case of you being an idiot at all.  Scala is a complicated language and someone else will inevitably run into a similar problem.  Good catch.